# Rails rake db:create not working

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

**Hey everyone!  I am having trouble setting up a MySQL database for my rails application.  Here are the contents of my database.yml file:**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_name_dev
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_name_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_name_pro
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

**I also replaced `gem sqlite3` with `gem mysql` in my gemfile and ran `bundle install`.  Now I am trying to create the database for the first time with `rake db:create`.  I am getting the following error:**

```
$ rake db:create --trace
(in c:/Users/Kvass/documents/programming/ruby/app_name)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
couldn't parse YAML at line 1 column 0
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application/configu
ration.rb:88:in `database_configuration'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railtie
s/databases.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in exec
ute'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invo
ke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_c
all_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `block in invo
ke_prerequisites'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prereq
uisites'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `block in invo
ke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_c
all_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'

c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 lev
els) in top_level'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top
_level'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exc
eption_handling'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run
'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exc
eption_handling'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'

c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

**Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL server had not been running on my machine when I tried to run `rake db:create`. Careless mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &TEST
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

cucumber:
  <<: *TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

In my development process i use this config:

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: my_db
    encoding: utf8
    username: rails
    password: rails
    host: localhost
```